# Android Studio - Change button shape at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, runtime, android-button, shapes

I'm trying to change the button to a specific shape on click in Android Studio.

After the click the button should look kinda like that:
[image: illustration]

The bottom triangle thing doesn't need to be clickable. The sole purpose of it is to indicate, that there is a fragment opened beneath the button.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I will suggest to use .. **selector** in xml. and use two button after selection of button

Comment: @NitinKarande Could you show an example?

Comment: Kindly have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

#### Define an ImageButton

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ul_ts.emvsdktester.drawabletraining.Main3Activity">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/tributton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Notice that I've given it a background **"@drawable/tributton"**

#### Define tributton.xml inside drawable forlder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_path" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/my_normal_path" />
</selector>
```

Notice that there are two states, one if the button if pressed, and one for otherwise. You can change the state as you want.

#### Create my_path.xml inside drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#32c2b6"
        android:pathData="M0 0 L50 0 L50 50 L30 50 L25 60 L20 50 L0 50 Z"
        android:strokeColor="#9a1616" />

</vector>
```

#### Create my_normal_path.xml inside the drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="100"
    android:viewportWidth="100">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#d0ce5b"
        android:pathData="M0 0 L50 0 L50 50 L0 50 Z"
        android:strokeColor="#000000" />

</vector>
```

Here is the results:

#### Normal

[image]

#### Clicked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This article shows how to create a triangle shape using XML shape.

http://devdeeds.com/create-triangle-shape-using-xml-android/

You can use this shape to place it relative to your button(below it). First make it hidden and after button click make it visible.